# Prevent screen scrolling up when keyboard is shown in mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, mobile-safari, ios9

I'm building an Angularjs app that has a  at the bottom of one view.

Problem in mobile safari on iOS9:
When focusing the textarea the soft keyboard is shown and covers the lower part of the view.

How can I scroll the page up when the keyboard is visible so that the content (i.e. the textarea) is not covered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way you might prevent scrolling. Add `overflow:hidden` to the document body when your inputs are in focus.

```js
    function toArray (collection) {
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(collection);
    }

    function noScroll (event) {
        if (event.type === 'focus') {
            document.body.classList.add('no-scroll');
        }

        else if (event.type === 'blur') {
            document.body.classList.remove('no-scroll');
        }
    }

    var inputs = toArray(document.querySelectorAll('input'));


    inputs.forEach(function(input){
        input.addEventListener('focus',noScroll,false);
        input.addEventListener('blur',noScroll,false);
    });
```

```css
.no-scroll {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

To scroll the page up, you could use `document.body.scrollTop` when the inputs are in focus and set the value to the desired location.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will check that out.